# javascript - toFixed covert problem in (444.2).toFixed(14)

Tags: javascript, tofixed

as the title

when I use toFixed to convert the float

```
(0.2).toFixed(4) ->       0.2000
(444.2).toFixed(4) ->   444.2000
(0.2).toFixed(14) ->      0.20000000000000
(444.2).toFixed(14) ->  444.19999999999999  //why ?!!!
```

I could not understand that what causes this result.

Is any javascript method to avoid this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers cannot represent all decimals precisely in binary. one way to overcome this problem is using parseFloat:

```js
console.log(parseFloat((444.2).toFixed(14)));
```

Comment: Mmm... Actually, I need to use the `toFixed(14)` to display the price like `444.20000000000000`.
Thanks for your response. :D